# ASP.NET UserManager InvalidOperationException dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm trying to inject into my services the UserManager, RoleManager and my database (Entity framework) to retrieve it using a framework provider (my own). I inject the database like this:

```c#
services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(
        FrameworkBase.Construction.Configuration.GetConnectionString(
            "InternalUsersDatabaseConnection")));
```

**"FrameworkBase.Construction" is a property that I made. The framework works like this: It gets all services injected into the server and returns the singleton/transient/scoped instance**

This is how I get the RoleManager instance:

```c#
public static RoleManager<ApplicationRole> RoleManager =>
    FrameworkBase.Provider.GetService<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>();
```

And this how I register it into services:

```c#
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<BittureIdentityDbContext>()

  // Here
  .AddUserManager<ExtendUserManager>()
  .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>()

  .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Is there any notable bug?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Note that usings statics is probably a very bad idea, especially considering that Identity uses an EF database context and those are request scoped.

Comment: Yes. What you're doing here is the service locator *anti-pattern*, as in you should not be doing this. If you need something like `RoleManager`, inject `RoleManager` in your constructor.

Comment: @ChrisPratt But if I need RoleManager out a controller?

Comment: You inject it into anything your want. Same principle applies.